# Matplotlib Multicolored Lines with datetime64[ns] axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm following [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py) of multicolored lines from the matplotlib website.

I'm trying to plot a set time-series data with the line being colored according to a different array. In the below simple example, I'm plotting y=x^2 with the line being shaded according to its derivate, dy/dx = 2x.

When I use an x-axis of just float numbers, such as below, it works fine.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0,10, 60)
y = x ** 2
dydx = 2*x

# Create arrays needed for multicolored lines
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
norm = plt.Normalize(dydx.min(), dydx.max())

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,10))

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='jet', norm=norm)
lc.set_array(dydx)
lc.set_linewidth(2)
line = ax.add_collection(lc)
fig.colorbar(line, ax=ax)

ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
plt.show()
```

Which produces

[image: working graph of y=x^2 with shaded derivative]

However, if I'm trying to plot time series data (where the x-axis is a datetime64[ns] array), it doesn't work out. In the below example, I replace x with x_time.

```py
# Generate time array
ts = np.datetime64('2020-01-01T00:00:00')
te = np.datetime64('2020-01-01T01:00:00')
x_time = np.arange(ts, te, np.timedelta64(1,'m'), dtype='datetime64[ns]')

# Create arrays needed for multicolored lines
points = np.array([x_time, y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
norm = plt.Normalize(dydx.min(), dydx.max())

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,10))

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='jet', norm=norm)
lc.set_array(dydx)
lc.set_linewidth(2)
line = ax.add_collection(lc)
fig.colorbar(line, ax=ax)

ax.set_xlim(x_time.min(), x_time.max())
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
plt.show()
```

Which produces a figure with the right x any y axis ticks, but no line

[image]

Edit:
Okay, I figured out where the line went. When I create the `segments` array, it converts the `datetime64[ns]` to an integer representation. Normally, matplotlib is able to interpret that as a datetime but in this case, because of the `LineCollection`, it keeps it as an int

Setting `ax.set_xlim(segments[:,:,0].min(), segments[:,:,0].max())` shows my line, but the axis is wrong (doesn't show as a time). 
[image]

Comment: Remove the line `ax.set_xlim(x_time.min(), x_time.max())`. It sets the view limits to a totally different range than you have your data in.

Comment: No, that's not it. When I remove that line, it sets my x-axis to 0.0 -> 1.0, still with no line drawn on the frame. When it set it to `x_time.min()` and `x_time.max()`, it sets the x-axis correctly; from 00:00 to 01:00 on Jan 1st, 2020

Comment: Your comment did help point me in the right direction, however. See my edit in the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to

1. Convert the dates to numbers representing matplotlib's datetime format
2. Tell the axis that it should tick datetimes.

So:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0,10, 60)
y = x ** 2
dydx = 2*x

# Generate time array
ts = np.datetime64('2020-01-01T00:00:00')
te = np.datetime64('2020-01-01T01:00:00')
x_time = np.arange(ts, te, np.timedelta64(1,'m'), dtype='datetime64[ns]')
x_time = mdates.date2num(x_time)
# Create arrays needed for multicolored lines
points = np.array([x_time, y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
norm = plt.Normalize(dydx.min(), dydx.max())

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,10))

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='jet', norm=norm)
lc.set_array(dydx)
lc.set_linewidth(2)
line = ax.add_collection(lc)
fig.colorbar(line, ax=ax)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```